# Is there a way to bypass UWP restrictions on certain APIs?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I have experimented with creating a Windows-10 C++ UWP xaml application.

My motivation in choosing this platform was to avoid using multiple languages (C# for WPF gui, C++-CLI for interop) and only use C++ with some C++-CX.

My goal was to create an in-house tool for debugging a PCI driver, not to create some sort of highly secured windows store application.

It appeared to me that UWP application are very restrictive when it comes to using some WIN API functions. For instance, I can't use my static libraries because they use CreateFile & DeviceIoControl. I get an error that says: `error C3861: 'CreateFileA': identifier not found`.

Even if I somehow manage to link my native libraries (by hiding the use of these functions in .cpp files) those functions seem to fail at runtime.

Is there anyway to bypass those restrictions?
I only want to use this platform for its C++ UI capabilities.

Comment: Try uwp desktop bridge applications

Comment: The real question here is the proverbial "can of worms" -- xaml + idl 3.0 + cppwinrt .... is this the better future vs the win32 past?

Why not making non-uwp desktop gui apps with xaml+idl3.0+cppwinrt combo? And equaly important. Why not making server side apps (no gui) with cppWINRT ... ?

Comment: @DusanJovanovic: What's the significance of XAML in a non-UWP desktop GUI app?

Comment: @IInspectable Well I would say the general MSFT direction for WIN UI is based on XAML as a part of a toolchain. UWP or not. C++ or not.  Together with the effort of deprecating WIN32. Maybe something along these lines: https://youtu.be/LYelIAwH7w8 ...

Comment: @DusanJovanovic: The native Windows Common Controls have traditionally used the Resource Definition file format as its markup language. For roughly 3 decades now. Microsoft isn't going in any other direction. It's unclear, where you got that impression from. The only other non-UWP GUI technology is WPF. Which is largely feature-identical to UWP's GUI technology, but with a managed-only interface (for whatever reason). In essence, there really is only UWP and the Windows API as GUI technologies, with the latter not ever going to move towards XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the bad news. Indeed, if you don't match mentioned restrictions your choice is not UWP. Do WPF instead.

UWP apps are intended for centralized control. So that, you can distribute them via Store, limit their filesystem access, manage memory footprint & lifetime etc. You can think about it like an attempt to discontinue Win32 API (which is rather old, hacker-prone and anarchic) and employ sand-boxing as a superseder.

Comment: Dissapointing news indeed. What a shame these restrictions are not optional.

Comment: @NinaKaprez, you can't opt-in or opt-out them because it's a vital part of UWP ideology. Moreover, even having unused import references to 'CreateFileA' or similar WinAPI staff automatically rejects your app submission to MS Store.

Comment: @NinaKaprez: If the restrictions were optional, no-one would opt-in to restrict themselves, and we would still continue to write applications that need to run with administrator privileges. As an aside, you can access the majority of the UWP API surface from a regular Windows Desktop application. I believe work is underway to make the remaining parts available as well, most notably the UI. Currently, you need to use Desktop Bridge. See [Extend your desktop application with modern UWP components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend) for more details.

Comment: @IInspectable I was wondering if Microsoft would make The UWP UI available to regular desktop apps. In the latest VS update (15.7) they added pure native C++ with XAML UWP applications and native WinRT console app. But still, no C++ with Xaml for regular desktop.

Comment: @NinaKaprez: There has been discussion about that in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/229). I'm not sure what the current status is here. The supported option would be to use the Desktop Bridge technology, as explained in the link I posted previously. If the Desktop Bridge doesn't work for your use case, you should leave a comment on the UserVoice entry linked from the GitHub issue, explaining why. From your question it does appear, that the Desktop Bridge is a suitable solution, though.

Comment: @NinaKaprez, I might also add I would be rather surprised if XAML is not (in the near future) completely decoupled from UWP. If not already is. That is also part of an effort to deprecate WIN32. It is rather interesting MS Research had done this two year ago already: https://youtu.be/LYelIAwH7w8

Comment: @NinaKaprez One might think the issue is: UWP is already looking like one very big foot gun. To drop it, big, slow and sensitive maneuver is required.

Comment: DesktopBridge is a generally a horrible solution to the problems of IPC.  You must wrap what are usually syncronous APIs around async brokers, all the while introducing untold amounts of overhead.  Forget UWP, use WPF.

Comment: @NinaKaprez For an update on UWP UI for desktop apps have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550895/uwpxamlhost-control-uwp-controls-in-desktop-apps-info-and-status)

Comment: @nin: There's now partial support for XAML controls in Win32 desktop applications. See [UWP controls in desktop applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls). The technology is coined *"XAML islands"*.

Answer (score 2):

Many "old" win32 functions are still available or have become available in Windows 1803. Targeting the UWP API is of course different then the Win32 API. Microsoft has a list of official supported Win32 APIs at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis

CreateFileA is not on that list, but CreateFile2 is.

For device access UWP provides functionality in the namespace Windows.Devices.Custom

LoadLibrary\GetProcAddress can also be a solution.

Most of the restrictions only apply to UWP apps that are uploaded to the Store, and not  for a side by side loaded application. You can just create the package and put it on a local network share or http server.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely correct. It's the RuntimeBroker.exe process, that controls access to the Windows API. It does so, regardless of how the UWP application was installed (Store, side-loaded, MSIX).

Comment: Besides, it doesn't appear that 1803 introduced *any* new Windows API calls at all. Plus, [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) isn't available for UWP apps either, so you cannot get a handle to kernel32.dll to import `CreateFileA`. Even if you could, it would be rejected at runtime by the RuntimeBroker process. Have you actually tried this, or do you have a link to reference documentation that explains, that this were possible?

Comment: I am investigating my answer. The following is possible (tested in the debugger):
- create a standard C++ Win32 DLL that exports a function that has a call to CreateFile
- create a UWP app and use LoadPackagedLibrary and GetProcAddress to get the exported function. 
- Performing the call into CreateFile for "////L"\\\\?\\pci#..." fails however with an ACCESS_DENIED error, which normally works fine from a Win32 console app.
It seems that the device driver .inf file needs to set explicit security rights for UWP.

Comment: @VictorDerks Does your test fails when trying to open a simple file using CreateFile? I don't think that it is the driver that needs to have the security rights. The API will fail no matter what.

Comment: @VictorDerks..are you able to get Driver handler and do IOCTL?

Comment: I have not been able to get a handle to my driver. At the moment I have stopped my experiment.